# Method and Properties for AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Is anyone have any documentation for MailItem AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser?

For example:

```
For each objItem in folder.Items
For Each Recipient In objItem.Recipients
Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Name
Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.JobTitle
Next
Next
```

But there are other less obvious ones that are very useful (especially if you are building hierarchies) but undocumented (or at least I can't find it):

```
Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetExchangeUserManager.name
```

Maybe there are others for example `.division` (which doesn't seem to exist but
maybe there is a way to print all the available properties.)

Comment: Look at the [`ExchangeUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser) properties and methods?

Answer (score 1):

there's no .division, but department, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32681129)